# Search within a lookup that is on a field in a table

Tags: ms-access

I put a table into a form for users to enter data into.  I needed to put the table into the form because sometimes the users copy and paste several rows of data in while other times they enter it row by row.

There are some lookups on this table for several of the fields.  Many of these lookups have 1,000's of records associated with them.

Is there a way to start typing in the field and have the lookup limit what is available to select based on the text that is typed into the field?

I can't seem to do this without the use of another text box in the form but I would like to be able to do it right in the table field.

Comment: I have comboboxes with 1000's of items listed and AutoExpand Yes is usually sufficient. However, if you want to consider text in any position of string, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-32.html. Note the RowSource does not include an ID field. The criteria could be extended to use preceding wildcard: `Like '*" & _
                sNewStub & "*'"`. I have used this technique for unbound combobox used for form search/filter operation, not for data entry.

Comment: When you say "typed into the field" and "right in the table field", do you really mean "typed into combobox"? If you mean you want to do this directly in table, not a form, no that is not possible. And what do you mean by "put a table into a form" - bound form to table?

Comment: If you mean you made SourceObject of a subform container a table instead of a form, keep in mind that a form does allow copy/paste of rows. A form set as Datasheet can look and act very much like a table. Yet, still have advantages of a form.